# Work done in cyclic process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have been told that when $\Delta V=0$, work done will be zero $(W=0)$. I know that, in cyclic process $\Delta V$ will be zero, since it's a path function and $\mid W \mid$ i.e. magnitude of work done will be the area enclosed by the curve. But my doubt is when $\Delta V=0$, shouldn't $W$ also be zero in such processes?

Comment: If the W had been zero, the fuel combustion engines would have stopped working.

Comment: @orthocresol it certainly wasn't homework problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reversible work is $W=\int{PdV}$ over the path of the process.  This integral is not zero for the cyclic process (involving V changing) even through $\Delta V$ from beginning to end of the process is zero.  So, whoever told you that $W = 0$ when $\Delta V=0$ is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my answer but I think this is how it goes.

$\Delta G=-W$ (useful work);

$= \Delta H-T \Delta S$

$= P + \Delta V -T \Delta S$
Therefore even though $\Delta V$ is zero it does not imply that all the other terms are zero too. Therefore $W$ is not zero.